# How to check file format using io module?

Tags: python, file-io, io

I want to check (`image_file`) variable format
and verify if it's ".png" or ".jpg".

```
image_str = urlopen(url).read()
image_file = io.BytesIO(image_str)
```

`url` is a random file from reddit.

Answer (score 1):

The best library for this is probably `imghdr` which inspects images and identifies their file-type:

```
import imghdr

imghdr.what("/path/to/file")
# OR...
imghdr.what("", h=io.BytesIO(imge_str))
```

The documentation for the library is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `endswith`

In your case if `url` is a string with your file, you can use :

```
if url.endswith('.png'):
    ...
elif url.endswith('.jpg'):
    ...
```

Comment: thanks that's what i did